# $n$-th partial sum -- generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Consider a finite series $S_n:=\sum_{i=0}^n i\cdot2^i$. The generating function for infinite formal series $\sum i\cdot x^i$ is $$a(x)=x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},$$
hence $$\frac{a(2x)}{1-x}=\frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-2x)^2}$$
is generating function for $\sum_{n\ge0}S_nx^n$ and $$S_n=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left.\frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-2x)^2}\right|_{x=0}$$
But this does not really satisfy me. How can I derive the closed form $S_n=(n-1)2^{n+1}+2$ (using machinery of generating functions)?

Comment: you can use partial fractions, $\frac{2x}{(1-x)(1-2x)^2}=-\frac{4}{1-2x}+\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{2}{1-x}$

Comment: @razivo thanks, that worked well